# Disable button on UI form

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am running Access 2013. There are 3 UI buttons that users can choose from to enter data. At this moment I want to render one of the buttons inactive, or delete the button from the UI view. I can't delete the code behind the button because the other 2 areas look at the information. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just set it as not visible. What would the 'other 2 areas' look at in button code?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your phrasing:

> "render one of the buttons inactive"

Simply set the `Enabled` property of the button to `No` such that the button is greyed out and cannot be clicked.